# Gamma Stretch Disabling in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis, esri

ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap usually stretch geo tiff. We have some large tiff files and some of the sections do not look good when stretching is applied. I usually open them in QGIS and they look very useful without any stretching. In ArcMap, they are an options to [disable gamma stretching](http://www.gis.arkansas.gov/Docs/Imagery/Disable_Gamma_Stretch.pdf)  which shows a similar-looking raster as QGIS as shown in the image below.

[image]

I am trying to do the same in ArcGIS Pro 2.8. I am going to the symbology option of the raster and selecting the stretch type to "None". However, there is no option to disable the gamma stretching. The gamma values are 0.2,0.2,0.2 and making them 0,0,0 do not work.

[image]

Any known option to disable the gamma stretching in ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem. [Esri's documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/help/data/imagery/raster-data-display-decisions.htm), which could provide more info, implies that gamma values of 1.0 are neutral and don't increase or decrease the contrast. Did some testing and compared Pro images to ArcMap images (where the handy checkbox exists) and confirmed that setting gamma values to 1.0 in Pro is the equivalent of unchecking the Apply Gamma Stretch checkbox in ArcMap.